# How can I add a string to another in a specific place?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I had some difficulty solving this challenge :

For each word in words, add ‘d’ to the end of the word if the word ends in “e” to make it past tense. Otherwise, add ‘ed’ to make it past tense. Save these past tense words to a list called past_tense.

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
```

My attempt was :

```
enter code here:


words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []
for i in words:
   if i[-1] == "e":
       past_tense.append(i+"d")
   else:
       past_tense.append(i+"ed")
print(past_tense)
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help, hint `[-1]=='e'`

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You need to show us some attempt from your end before we help you, also look us `str.endswith`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a more pythonic way on doing this, but this is quite understandable!

Using `str.endswith`as mentioned in the comments, will save you a lot of time!

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
new_list=[]
for i in words:
    if i.endswith('e'):
        new_list.append(i+'d')
    else:
        new_list.append(i+'ed')
print(new_list)
```

This will output you past list!

```
['adopted', 'baked', 'beamed', 'confided', 'grilled', 'planted', 'timed', 'waved', 'wished']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an inline if-else construct in a list comprehension:

```
past_tense = [w + 'd' if w.endswith('e') else w + 'ed' for w in words]
```

Comment: You could factor out the `w + ` part:  `w + ('d' if ... else 'ed')`